# Which one best method for call a specific function at specific time , Job scheduler or alarm manager

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am communicating Bluetooth device with hardware. I want to send the data at a particular time into Bluetooth module which is the best method to schedule the call function, Which one I should use alarm manager or job scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should AlarmManager. You won't have that control with Jobscheduler. Scheduled jobs in JobScheduler will be executed based on criteria defined by OS  which you cannot influence. If your use-case demands execution at particular time then AlarmManager should be your choice.

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#restrictions):

> Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow())
>   are deferred to the next maintenance window.
>
> - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
> - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Comment: Please check this link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935965/how-do-i-resolve-android-bluetooth-bluetoothgatt-getservice-java-util-uuid-on?noredirect=1#comment86968013_49935965

Comment: @VenkateshT what do you want to highlight from the link?

Comment: Please check that actual problem when i'm using alarm manager.

Comment: The issue is not with the AlarmManager, its with your Service. Update that question with complete class and let me know.

Comment: Please check I've included service also.

Comment: @VenkateshT The two questions are different. For this question, the answer I provided is the solution. For other question, we need to check why its the case. If this answer was helpful then remember to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @VenkateshT no problem. Hope you manage to solve other problem

Comment: If I've doubt in future ask ur help

Comment: @VenkateshT sure. Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on your task if you want to perform the task when the app is killed also the device in DOZE mode then please use alarm manager with job scheduler otherwise you can use job scheduler.

Here is the proper method to schedule alarm.

```
public static void startAlarm(Context context, int minutes) {
        Logger.print("AlarmReceiver startAlarm  called");
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, WakefulBroadcastReceiverService.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction("testAPP");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123451, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        long alarmPeriodicTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + Utils.getTimeInMilliSec(Constant.TimeType.MINUTE, minutes);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

For the job scheduler user please use FirebaseJob dispatcher for lower version support

Comment: If I'm using alarm manager null exception problem occurred during at data sent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935965/how-do-i-resolve-android-bluetooth-bluetoothgatt-getservice-java-util-uuid-on?noredirect=1#comment86968013_49935965